# Unable to open Excel file in Write mode even after using 'ReadOnly:=False' in the Workbooks.Open

Tags: excel, vba

While trying to open an excel file using VB script in write mode using the `Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=False)` method, getting the error message stating that the file is opened in read-only mode. Getting error message

> Run-time error '1004': We can't save 'testqry1.xlsm' because the file is read-only. To keep your changes, you'll need to save the workbook with a new name or in a different location

The vb script I used:

```
Sub read_Test1()
Dim val
Dim lrow
ReDim cell_val(1)
 
Dim fp, fn, newFileName
fn = ThisWorkbook.FullName
fp = ThisWorkbook.Path

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWrk = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(fn, ReadOnly:=False)
Set ws = objWrk.Sheets("Sheet2")
RowCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

' Redefine array size dynamically based on number of Rows
ReDim cell_val(RowCount)
ReDim newCell_val(RowCount)

For j = 1 To RowCount
    cell_val(j - 1) = ws.Cells(j, 1)
Next

For k = 1 To 3
     Dim str_tmp
     If (InStr(cell_val(k - 1), "<DIV>")) Then
        str_tmp = Replace(cell_val(k - 1), "<DIV>", "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    End If
    newCell_val(k - 1) = str_tmp
Next

For m = 1 To 3
     ws.Cells(m, 2).value = newCell_val(m - 1)
     objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
Next

End Sub
```

I have also tried Workbook.ChangeFileAccess method but still in vain.

Comment: Afaik the ReadOnly parameter is by default False, why are you trying to open the file you're using again in a separate version of Excel in write? Unless you're using the code in a read-only version of the file, you're not going to be able to get a write-version going.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, I have pasted my complete script along with the error message.

Comment: thanks for all the help... I was able to resolve the write issue and I will mark it as a closed question

Answer (score -3):

You are open the same Workbook that you are working, my adevice is not open the Workbook and use ThisWorkbook.Save, to save, instead of objWrk.Save.